# InfoPath Unique datetime with milliseconds as field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

Currently I am using concat(substring(now(), 1, 4), substring(now(), 6, 2), substring(now(), 9, 2), substring(now(), 12, 2), substring(now(), 15, 2), substring(now(), 18, 2)) to get a unique ticket number in a field but we have run across a situation where 2 users created at the same second.  So I would like to add milliseconds without having to program it in the backend.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible with default InfoPath forms. You will have to write your own codebehind solution. You can create an invisible field in InfoPath and query the date and time using a custom data connection. A similar solution can be found [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/files/folders/qrules/entry67664.aspx).

A much simpler solution would be using usernames if it is acceptable in your case. Like this:
GregContoso_2013_08_12_15_43

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable for you, you can create a new item in another list and get it's ID as a unique field after ticket number. Similar to Greg's offer, like this:2013_08_12_15_43_1 etc. List item ID's will always be unique, so maybe this can solve your problem.